# How can I save dropdown list value imported from Google Sheets when I submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form with some fields and one of them is a dropdown list of names imported from google sheets.

The form works fine, the dropdown retreive the available values on google sheet but when i submit it, the field with values from dropdown stays in blank. It seems that is missing the save of value before the submit task.

I already try some solutions presented on web but they didn´t worked and i am stuck. Can you help me to find what is missing? Thank you.

My code.gs file is

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html').evaluate();
  return html.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}

function getList() { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var nameSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NAMES"); 
  var getLastRow = nameSheet.getLastRow();  
  return nameSheet.getRange(2, 1, getLastRow - 1, 1).getValues();  
}

function startForm()
{ 
  var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Droplist');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
}

function addMenu()
{
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom');
  menu.addItem('Dropdown Form', 'startForm');
  menu.addToUi(); 
}

function onOpen(e)
{
  addMenu(); 
}

function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var firstResponse = form.getResponses()[0];
  var dropdownResponse = firstResponse.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  Logger.log(dropdownResponse);
}
```

And my html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
  function loadnames() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {
      var nameSelect = document.getElementById("name");
      console.log(ar);
      
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = "";
      option.text = "";
      nameSelect.appendChild(option);
    
      ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
      {    
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = item[1];
        option.text = item[0];
        nameSelect.appendChild(option);    
      });
    
    }).getList();
  };
  
  function onSelect() 
  {
    var nameID = document.getElementById("name").value;
  };

</script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                var value = $("#name option:selected");
                alert(value.text());
            });
        });
</script>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
    <h1>Registo</h1>
    <form  method="post" autocomplete="off" name="google-sheet">
                
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label  class="form-label">Data</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date"/>
        </div>
          
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label  class="form-label">Trabalhador</label>
            <select id="name" onchange="onSelect()" ></select><br>
            <script>loadnames();</script>
    </div>
        
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" for="project">Projeto:</label>
            <select id="project" name="project">
                <option value="IS054" selected>IS054</option>
                <option value="IS058">IS058</option>
                <option value="IS064">IS064</option>
                <option value="IS077">IS077</option>
                <option value="IS999">IS999</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" for="epi">EPI:</label>
            <select id="epi" name="epi">
                <option value="Luvas finas" selected>Luvas Finas</option>
                <option value="Luvas Grossas">Luvas Grossas</option>
                <option value="Oculos">Oculos</option>
                <option value="Mascaras">Mascaras</option>
                <option value="Botas Trabalho">Botas Trabalho</option>
                <option value="Botas Agua">Botas Agua</option>
                <option value="Calças Trabalho">calças</option>
                <option value="Fato Chuva">Fato Chuva</option>
                <option value="Colete">Colete</option>
                <option value="Roupa Termica">Roupa Termica</option>
                <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
            </select>
        </div>
                        
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" for="notes">Obs:</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="notes" placeholder="Escrever" rows="4" style="resize: vertical;"></textarea>
        </div>            
        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submeter</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
    <script>
      
      //Send submit data to google sheet
        const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzPb4TfaNqZBNBBUiIoSUibekC4iiTWiP5bJZH-yIpQNHAxePK9jJQYRltBiMWkzQxk/exec'
        const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
      
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
            .then(response => alert("Registo Efetuado. Obrigado!"))
            .catch(error => alert("Registo já existe na base de dados!!"))
            
      //Clear ao form fields
            form.reset()
        })
      </script>
      
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
    
  </body>
</html>
```

To keep value from dropdown list and be abble do send it to google sheet when submit the form.

Comment: Can you provide the script of Web Apps of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzPb4TfaNqZBNBBUiIoSUibekC4iiTWiP5bJZH-yIpQNHAxePK9jJQYRltBiMWkzQxk/exec`? By the way, what is `myFunction()` in your Google Apps Script?

Comment: myfunction is nothing. It was a try i made and i didn´t deleted it.

Comment: There is no script. That address is from google sites, where i published the codes in above.